# Xamarin iOS - Keyboard disappears for no reason

Tags: xamarin.ios, keyboard-events

I experience a strange behavior in a Xamarin iOS app. I have a UITextField inside a MvxTableViewController. When the user tries to write something in the field the keyboard disappears if the iPad is moved (tilted towards the person), rotated or if someone slightly touches the keyboard with his sleeve. The strange behavior disappears if the screen rotation is locked. I don't use any custom code, despite the usual bindings specific to MvvmCross. This strange behavior is present just in this screen, all the other UITextFields work as expected. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to post your code?

Comment: It's a pretty big class and I'm afraid that I am not allowed to post it here.